# Change type to non-optional after get rid of nils by applying filter

Tags: swift, option-type, swift5

```
let elements: [(Int?, Int?)] = [(1, 2), (2, 1), (3, nil), (nil, 3), (5, 6), (6, 5)]
let result = elements.filter { $0.0 != nil } as! [(Int, Int?)]
```

Is there a more clean way to get partly non-optional type as a result? Without force-unwrapping...
When we filtering out nils it's should be obvious to compiler that we will get something non-optional. Like it is in the case when we applying compactMap for example.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a way without force-unwrapping that is still mostly readable:

```
let result = elements.compactMap { $0 as? (Int, Int?) }
```

Printing out `result` shows that it works:

```
[(1, Optional(2)), (2, Optional(1)), (3, nil), (5, Optional(6)), (6, Optional(5))]
```

Answer (score 3):

The only way without force unwrapping (`!`) I could think of is:

```
let result = elements.compactMap { (x, y) in x.map { ($0, y) } }
```

But that sacrifices readability. I would just keep the force unwrapping to be honest. It's not an "absolute evil" thing. Sometimes you need it.